# How much friction arise from the tires?

Tags: tire

Does anyone know how much friction (rolling resistance) arise from the tires? I know this heavily depends on type of tire, their air pressure and the type of surface. I would therefore like to see any source describing the friction on any combination of these factors. I am only interested in knowledge that can be verified.

The reason why I am interested is to understand what the maximum potential is if developing new types of tires.

Comment: Welcome to the site; interesting question. The [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) site might also be a resource.

Comment: Thank you, but this takes testing to find out, the physics guys won't be able to calculate it.

Comment: If all you're looking for is a source, then the best source is Chapter 6 of Wilson's [Bicycling Science](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0262731541). However, wouldn't a better question be something like, "which factors influence bicycle tire rolling resistance and how are they measured?"

Comment: It is a valid question, especially if compared to other "drags" on the bike.  I suspect at 1MPH in still air tire friction swamps other factors, but I don't know where you'd find the data to prove it.  (I do recall, though, that a few of the bike tire mfgrs have produced some pretty good docs that may touch on this.)

Comment: @R. Chung I have updated my question to clarify. Does that source you have still answer the question? I know the answer to "which factors influence bicycle tire rolling resistance and how are they measured?", I just need some examples on how much friction tires can cause.

Comment: By 'friction' I suppose you mean 'grip', i.e. 'how well do the tires hold the road when you're braking or accelerating'.

Comment: Any answers here should probably have citations, similar to how [Skeptics](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/) does things. (Mod hat off, this is just my opinion.)

Comment: @David: there are 4 types of friction involved, which do you mean? (1) static friction (how well tires hold to the road normall), (2) dynamic friction (how well they stop while skidding), (3) rolling resistance (how much the tire resists being rolled) and (4) air resistance (how much the tire contributes).

Comment: @freiheit Thank you. I mean the third type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the rolling resistance from [terrymorse.com](http://www.terrymorse.com/bike/rolres.html). Its the top link from a google search on "bicycle tyre rolling resistance".

[image]

Comment: Yeah, there's some good info on that link, including another chart that shows rolling resistance at 23-46 watts at 18.6 mph (pressure unspecified).  Unfortunately, there's no data for tires wider than 28.

Comment: Omg! I've been searching for the wrong things all this time! Thank you!

Comment: That's a good chart but I didn't mention it earlier because it's both dated and incomplete. That chart is based on tests done about 20 years ago at the Continental Tire facility using a large diameter asphalt-surface driven drum; no other surfaces were checked and it is known that road, tire, tube, tire-rim attachment, and additional suspension characteristics can affect total rolling drag. In particular, inflection or "break" points in rolling drag have been observed in some tests on other types of surfaces with increasing pressure.

Comment: As I mentioned above, the old Continental tests were performed on a single (homogeneous) surface. You can see some examples (but with no detailed results) of contemporary test rigs here: http://www.bikeradar.com/news/article/bicycle-tires-puncturing-the-myths-29245/
In addition, there are ways that interested amateurs can measure rolling resistance at home or in the field, on a variety of road surfaces.